# Objective-c: why private ivars are not hidden from the outside access when using KVC

Tags: objective-c, private, encapsulation, setvalue, ivars

After trying to access ivars using KVC, I have noticed that there was no protection on private and protected ivars. It doesn't matter what I put a in front of the ivar (private or protected keyword) - an ivar is always a public ivar when using KVC method "setValue". Here is my code where all of the seven ivars and properties are changeble outside the class instance:

```
//************ interface file ***************//
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
@public    
  NSNumber *public_num;
@protected 
  NSNumber *protected_num;
@private 
  NSNumber *private_num;
  NSNumber *private_property;
}
@property (retain) NSNumber *public_property;
@property (retain) NSNumber *private_property;
@end

//********* implementation file *********//
@interface MyClass(){
@private
  NSNumber *very_private_num;
}
@property (retain) NSNumber *very_private_property;
@end

@implementation MyClass
@synthesize public_property, private_property, very_private_property;
@end

//****** main **********//
MyClass *myClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];

[myClass setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"public_num"];
[myClass setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:@"protected_num"];
[myClass setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3] forKey:@"private_num"];
[myClass setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:4] forKey:@"public_property"];
[myClass setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5] forKey:@"private_property"];
[myClass setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:6] forKey:@"very_private_num"];
[myClass setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:7] forKey:@"very_private_property"];

NSNumber *l_public_num = [myClass valueForKey:@"public_num"];
NSNumber *l_protected_num = [myClass valueForKey:@"protected_num"];
NSNumber *l_private_num = [myClass valueForKey:@"private_num"];
NSNumber *l_public_property = [myClass valueForKey:@"public_property"];
NSNumber *l_private_property = [myClass valueForKey:@"private_property"];
NSNumber *l_very_private_num = [myClass valueForKey:@"very_private_num"];
NSNumber *l_very_private_property = [myClass valueForKey:@"very_private_property"];

NSLog(@"public_num = %@, protected_num = %@, private_num = %@, public_property = %@, private_property = %@, very_private_num = %@, very_private_property = %@", l_public_num, l_protected_num, l_private_num, l_public_property, l_private_property, l_very_private_num, l_very_private_property);
```

The result of the output> public_num = 1, protected_num = 2, private_num = 3, public_property = 4, private_property = 5, very_private_num = 6, very_private_property = 7.

Even if the ivar declared at private interface, it is still changeable outside the class. So how do I have to enforce encapsulation and "to protect my ivars from evil other programmers" :)

Comment: So far, I have noticed that the only way to have "sort of a private method" is to declare a pure method in private interface (without using synthesize). Then compiler warns about method being not found. But still code and the method is executable :). I wrote    NSLog(@"Inside hiddenMethod\n") in the hiddenMethod and then executed that method from the main and I got the message in debug window.
}

Comment: There are no private methods in Objective-C.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

NSObject conforms to the [NSKeyValueCoding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) informal protocol. This defines `setValue:forKey:` and `valueForKey:`. `setValue:forKey:` and `valueForKey:` search for a way to access the value of the key according to [specific search rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/SearchImplementation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000955) which includes directly accessing the instance variable. This direct accessing is controlled by `accessInstanceVariablesDirectly` method which is a part of the NSKeyValueCoding informal protocol, which by default returns `YES`, allowing those methods to directly access the instance variables and as a result not really making them private as such. They are still private from direct access.

To resolve this, you will have have to override the methods mentioned above and defined in the `NSKeyValueCoding` informal protocol to prevent their access.

As mentioned by Abizern, properties for private variables are still accessible since Objective-C has no concept of private methods.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still trying to learn obj-c, therefore I thought that KVC is the direct access way (outside the class)...

Comment: What do think, why those keywords as "private" and "protected" are used in interface declaration if they have no real impact? They are confusing people, especially the begginers. Moreover, why there is so called "private interface" that resides in implementation file if there is no real "privatness"?

Comment: I work primarily with Obj-C and C++ and in both languages there are ways to get around access specifiers such as private and protected. Really it is just a guide or indicator to developers using that class that they should not touch anything that isn't marked as public. Whilst this example is a library work around, there is also no reason why someone using a library that has easily modifiable headers cannot just remove @private from the header altogether.

Answer (score 4):

Don't declare a `@property` for an iVar if you really want it to remain private.

It isn't the iVar that is no longer private. The Objective-C runtime doesn't have a concept of private methods. Since using `@property` and @`synthesize` generates KVC compliant accessor methods, you can always call the methods, regardless of whether the backing iVar is private or not.

But it isn't as bad as you think. Using the methods you have doesn't directly change the iVar - it goes through the setters. If you need extra protection you can write your own setter that implements whatever protection you need.

If you just declare an iVar as `@private` and don't make it KVC compliant - it will remain private. Of course; you then can't use KVC or KVO on that iVar, but if you wanted to be able to use them you shouldn't be declaring it as a private iVar.

Comment: Sorry for the mess. I mean, I put the only private ivar with no @property and @synthesize. Still, ivar is accessable from outside using KVC method setValue, and the output of 11 is shown.

Comment: Don't declare it as a `@property` for a start. Don't implement Setters and getters for that iVar. Here a [quick guide to KVC](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/KeyValueCoding.html)

Comment: I put the full code in the first comment with no @property and @synthesize. And I didn't implement setter and getter for that ivar. Still, I can access it with setValue. So where is the trick :)

Comment: ATTENTION: **The answer totally wrong**. If inherit from NSObject, the class is KVC compliant. KVC will access the corresponding instance variable directly on finding no accessor method for a property **by default**. If this is **not** what you want, return NO in `+ accessInstanceVariablesDirectly`

Comment: Also, declare as `@private` is useless.

Answer (score 3):

Today, I have noticed interesting thing. Stephen Kochan, in his "Programming in Objective c 2.0" book, states one interesting fact about obj-c and c relation: "When you define a new class and its instance variables, those instance variables are actually stored inside a structure". Therefore, the direct access to such ivar could be made using -> operator. So, finaly, I found where such keywords as @private and @protected really matters. If I try directly to change public ivar value in the main program using then everything is ok - the value will be changed. But if I try changing private ivar - then the compiler will warn me about private_num being a private ivar

```
myClass->public_num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:11];
myClass->private_num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:11]; // compiler will complain and reject the compilation
```

But since default KVC mechanism still allows access to private or public ivars outside the class, the real encapsulation and protection must be explicitly enforced by overriding setValue:forKey: and valueForKey: methods that are declared in the NSKeyValueCoding informal protocol and by default implemented in NSObject

Answer (score 1):

I'll add my two cents to this old question.

I think the `@private`, `@protected` is there also to prevent access to a variable using the '->' operator.

Imagine you have a iVar called `myPrivateVar` declared like below:

```
@interface MyClass:NSObject{
  @public
    NSArray *myPrivateVar;
}
```

So even if you implement the below class method to return `NO` and don't have accessors declared for the iVar:

```
+accessInstanceVariablesDirectly{
    return NO;
}
```

the variable is still accessible if you use **`myClassObj->myPrivateVar`**;

On the other hand if you just make the `@public` to `@private` and don't implement `accessInstanceVariableDirectly`, the variable is still accessible by using KVC:

```
[myClassObj valueForKey:@"myPrivateVar"];
```

(and not accessible via `myClassObj->myPrivateVar`)

So to make your iVar completely private it should be declared as `@private` and also `accessInstanceVariablesDirectly` should be implemented to return `NO`.

Answer (score 0):

forbid via an override of the kvc entries:

```
@implementation MONObject

- (id)valueForKey:(NSString *)key
{
/* enforce it */
    return nil;
}

- (void)setValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key
{
/* enforce it */
}

/* and so on */

@end
```

Comment: Thanks. IMHO, I would conclude that obj-c has no real private mechanism. It is a matter of workarounds to simulate the desirable privatness and to override the default behaviour of the compiler (or runtime?). But then, it is strange why those keywords as "private" and "protected" are used in declaration if they have no real impact. I think they are confusing people, especially the begginers.

Comment: IMHO, it is the competency of a programmer to follow a working conventions by using properties via custom or synthesized setters and getters to control the values of ivars/properties. IMHO, the encapsulation is used only as a working convention. By the way, do you simulate / use private ivars / properties / methods in your real projects?

Comment: use a private c++ ivar, or private class where you need it

Comment: i write more c++ than objc - i choose the right language for the task.